# Old view Controller not closing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

When I Login to my app from LoginViewController.swift, I go to HomeViewController.swift. From HomeViewController.swift if I logout my app, I again go to LoginViewController.swift. Then what i see, my LoginViewController still have data filled in the text fields, that means my old login view controller is not closing.

Please help me with this

Comment: Are presenting HomeVC modally and LoginVC as the parent?

Answer (score 1):

And will not close. When you pop HomeViewController, iOS will restore LoginViewController state, and then, login will appear.

To make what you want, just implement something like this in your LoginViewController:

Swift code:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    textFieldLogin.text = ""
    textFieldPass.text = ""
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, experiment with the types of segues you are using.